# Do I use 'of' or 'by' in connection with artist's work?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I often write about works of art and am unsure if I'm doing it correctly. What I am trying to express is that if you go to this exhibition you will see artworks by certain artists. Is this correct:

- The exhibition features works **by** VALIE EXPORT, Frieda Kahlo and Georgia O'Keeffe.

or

- The exhibition features works **of** VALIE EXPORT, Frieda Kahlo and
  Georgia O'Keeffe. (?)

Does it change anything if I put a "the" in?

- The exhibition features *the* works of VALIE EXPORT, Frieda Kahlo and
  Georgia O'Keeffe.

Does it change if I use "work" instead of "works" or is it the same?

Are both correct or just one? And if so, why?

Really thankful for answers!

Answer (score 1):

- A book is written by an author
- A painting is painted by a painter.
- A meal is cooked by a cook or person.

However, there is at least one case, if not more, where one might use OF:

The exhibition showed works of A, B and C.

If  you want to emphasize **who they "come from", you can use "of".** And if there are several artists.

**The paintings of Rembrandt, van Eyck and Bosch** were not part of the exhibition.

If you want to emphasize **the action used to create them, use "by".**

- There is no doubt that this painting was [painted] by Degas.

**But please bear this in mind**: Often, and "of" will be replaced by a possessive:

- Picasso's works or Picasso's work were not part of the exhibition in San Diego.
- Rembrandt's self-portrait is very well known in art circles.

As for work or works, generally, work refers to the action of painting by an artist***or*** a single painting. A work by x means a painting by x [or sculpture].

- **Much work** on the painting was done outside.
- A work of art is a glorious thing.
- A work by Picasso hung in the hall.
- Works by Picasso were scattered throughout the mansion.

Answer (score 0):

The first version using "by" is correct, but I think the second version using "of" should be

> The exhibition features the work of VALIE EXPORT, Frieda Kahlo and Georgia O'Keeffe.

This has **work** in the singular, because the noun **work** is being used in a different way. In your first version, **the works** are **the works of art**. In the second version, **work** is used in its more general sense: the output of those artists.